# PostgreSQL - make two selects in two columns

Tags: postgresql

How can i add order, group by and limit for each arr in query?

users table:

```
╔════╦══════════════╦
║ id ║  name        ║ 
╠════╬══════════════╬
║  1 ║ Jeff Atwood  ║
║  2 ║ Geoff Dalgas ║
║  3 ║ Jarrod Dixon ║
║  4 ║ Joel Spolsky ║ 
╚════╩══════════════╩
```

Output query example without filter and limit:

```
SELECT JSON_AGG(u) filter (where id > 1) as arr1,
       JSON_AGG(u) filter (where id < 3) as arr2
FROM users u
```

Expected:

```
╔═══════════════════╦═════════════════════╦
║ arr1              ║  arr2               ║ 
╠═══════════════════╬═════════════════════╬
║ [{id:1, name: ''},║ [{id:1, name: ''},  ║ 
║ {id:2, name: ''}] ║ {id:2, name: ''}]   ║ 
╚═══════════════════╩══════════════════════
```

Query arguments example for one array:

```
SELECT *
    FROM ps
    LEFT JOIN u on u.id = ps.id
    WHERE ps.date <= now()
    GROUP BY ps.id
    ORDER BY ps.date DESC
```

Comment: Please add more clarity in the question by adding your desired output

Comment: @AkhileshMishra same output as in example query but with limit and order for each of arr

Comment: your question is not clear ..  try explain better ... add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @scaisEdge added example

Comment: Is your example 2 rows or a single one (ie a single json object). It looks like 2 separate rows (with each 2 columns with 1 json object), but then why are you using an aggregate function (`JSON_AGG`) without a `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @Marth i just need to make 2 selects with different arguments from one table and put them in 2 separate arrays of objects

Comment: @ZiiMakc: Ok. And do you always want to limit the json array to only 2 elements, or is this dynamic?

Comment: @Marth it's dynamic. I would use  group by + order + join. Added full query for one select

Answer (score 1):

**Order BY**

You can put order by with in aggregate function like this:

```
SELECT json_agg(users.* order by id desc) FILTER (WHERE id > 1 ) AS arr1,
       json_agg(users.*) FILTER (WHERE id < 2) AS arr2
FROM users;
```

As per my understanding `LIMIT` is not allowed to use in this way i.e. array wise

Comment: i need limit :( Maybe i should just make separate query if it's hard to combine them?

Comment: I do not understand why you need limit, Please show the output you want from a set of input that is eliminated by the limit and indicate why. Also, include a set that was not eliminated. However, I would think 2 queries is NOT the solution; we just need to understand the limiting factors.